# pip commands don't release console

Tags: windows, python-2.7, terminal, pip

Using python 2.7.

Encounter a very weird behavior when using python pip on a specific server (it doesn't happen in other servers).

No matter which pip command I run (install/list/freeze/etc), when the command finishes execution, it doesn't "release" the console , it remains stuck in "pip mode".

In order to get back to the console, I have to press ctl+c and then an exception is thrown.. here is a print screen of the partial error:

[image]

I tried to reinstall python but that didnt change anything.

Anybody have an idea?

Comment: See my answer below please.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding `--no-cache-dir` option to the commands, e.g `pip install argh --no cache-dir` .
I'm not sure how it is related but results speak for themselves